# dateFromComponents gives Wrong date

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I am trying to get a `Date` object from `NSDateComponents`, but `Calendar.date(from: Components)` is giving a date one day before the date that was in my original components.

```
let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
let dateComponents = calendar!.components([.Year , .Month , .Weekday, .Day], fromDate: NSDate())
dateComponents.year = 2015
dateComponents.month = 9
dateComponents.day = 1
```

---

```
po calendar!.dateFromComponents(dateComponents)
▿ Optional(2015-08-31 18:30:00 +0000)
  - Some : 2015-08-31 18:30:00 +0000
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the time zone with `calendar` object to `UTC`, and the try to get `Date` from the `calendar`.

```
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")!
```

Comment: Hey can you give me the reason for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

It's giving you the `UTC` time zone, Just convert the Date by usning NSDateFormatter like this, you will get your answer -

```
let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
let dateComponents = calendar!.components([.Year , .Month , .Weekday, .Day], fromDate: NSDate())
dateComponents.year = 2015
dateComponents.month = 9
dateComponents.day = 1


let df = NSDateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let datestring = df.stringFromDate(calendar!.dateFromComponents(dateComponents)!)
print(datestring)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But i think, i need to set Timezone to get the correct date.